# jade template rendering with express

Tags: pug

This is my app.js file.

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();


app.set('view engine','jade');
app.set('views',__dirname+'/templates')
app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.send('index');
    });

app.listen(3000);
```

This is how my index.jade looks like

```
 html(lang= "en")

head 
    title Landing Page
body
    h1 "The future"
    p "Hi my name is shah"
```

Both app.js and templates files are in the folder. The file index.jade is in templates file. I have checked the dependencies in package.json file and jade dependency is there. When I run the server and it says index instead of locating the index.jade file in the folder and rendering it. I am sure it has something to do with file organization. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing 
    `res.send('index');`
with
    `res.render('index');`
and make sure you have installed that jade dependency by running `npm install`.

Reference : http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html